# Run WP-CLI using PHP

Tags: plugins, php, wp-cli, docker

I've installed WP-CLI on the Mac and my next step is to execute WP-CLI commands using PHP script.

I've tried to implement it the following way but I do not see anything happening. Can someone please look at my code and tell me that what I'm doing wrong?

I'm using Docker and have WP installed in `Docker/xamp/www/wordpress_wwws/htdocs` directory

Do I need to execute the PHP code from within the WP directory or can It be in any directory on the server?

```
define( 'WP_CLI_ROOT', '/usr/local/bin/wp' );
include WP_CLI_ROOT . '';
$output = shell_exec("wp --info");
echo "<pre>".$output."</pre>";
```

Do I need to configure and setup wp-cli with my PHP files?

Also, when I type wp --info on my terminal the following information comes up. Nothing is appearing beside the Package Dir & global config. do I also need to make adjustments to wp-cli?

```
MAC-00343:htdocs mike$ wp --info
PHP binary: /usr/bin/php
PHP version:    5.6.30
php.ini used:   
WP-CLI root dir:    phar://wp-cli.phar
WP-CLI vendor dir:  phar://wp-cli.phar/vendor
WP_CLI phar path:   /Users/mike/Docker/xamp/www/wordpress_wwws/htdocs
WP-CLI packages dir:    
WP-CLI global config:   
WP-CLI project config:  
WP-CLI version: 1.3.0
```

Any help or suggestions will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Regarding the `wp --info` output, that makes sense.  If you don't have any packages installed (see `wp package --help` or a global configuration files (`wp-cli.yml`) then those items would be blank.

You can run the `wp` command from any location.  If you're anywhere within your website's folder structure it will automatically detect the site you're on by navigating up the folder tree until it finds a wp-config.php file.

If running wp from a location outside your site's folder structure, you'll have to specify the `path`, like this:

`wp --path=/path/to/wordpress/site/ core version`

As for executing commands from within PHP, this following works for me:

**test.php**

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec("wp --info");
echo "<pre>".$output."</pre>";
?>
```

running `php test.php` from the command line, I get:

```
PHP binary:    /usr/local/Cellar/php71/7.1.1_12/bin/php
PHP version:    7.1.1
php.ini used:   /usr/local/etc/php/7.1/php.ini
WP-CLI root dir:    phar://wp-cli.phar
WP-CLI vendor dir:  phar://wp-cli.phar/vendor
WP_CLI phar path:   /Users/shawnhooper
WP-CLI packages dir:    /Users/shawnhooper/.wp-cli/packages/
WP-CLI global config:
WP-CLI project config:
WP-CLI version: 1.3.0
```

Also there is quite a lengthy discussion on running WP-CLI commands from PHP in the project's official GitHub repo.  You might find this issue of interest: https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/issues/1924

Comment: Thanks Shawn, the suggestions on the WP-CLI github page helped me execute commands from the the PHP script.