# Install WordPress using PHP

Tags: wp-cli

I just want to download, install and setup WordPress using PHP.

I can do it using **WP-CLI** and **command lin**e and it worked.

Now I want to do it using with **WP-CLI** and **PHP**.

I read [Run WP-CLI using PHP](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/277365/run-wp-cli-using-php)

The answer of above question suggest following code to test.

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec("wp --info");
echo "<pre>".$output."</pre>";
?>
```

I tried it, but it return nothing. How can I solve this issue?

Notes :

- I am testing this with localhost (XAMPP).
- `wp --info` working fine on command prompt.
- `shell_exec()` working fine with other normal non wp commands.

Comment: if you are trying to do it from the web, than it will never work as no secure host will let you run a shell script

Comment: @MarkKaplun Even in dedicated server?

Comment: You can get this to work on a dedicated server (though it may not be a the best idea for security reasons as Mark Kaplun pointed out) but it will require some setup to allow the apache user that executes php to run these commands.

Comment: a dedicated server.... maybe if you are the only one that uses it, but this is a security smell, and if you configure the server to allow this any attacker that will succeed in executing a php script on your server will "own" it. If you are looking into creating wordpress site via a web interface you will have to find a more subtle ways.

Comment: sorry, but downvoted this, as this sounds like a permission issue somewhere which will be impossible to even guess without access to your machine. Regardless, my previous comments stand, this is not the way to go whatever you are trying to do.

Comment: @MarkKaplun This is the requirements. This is a client management system. When I add a client, I want to automatically install and setup WordPress for client. That's why I am going to do this. I don't know any alternative methods to my requrment. Do you have any idea?

Comment: IMHO you just do not do it from web server which is web accessible. One option to avoid it is to write the info for the new site in a special DB and have a cron process (OS one, not the WP one) that runs every minute and creates sites based on it. You are still open for people creating sites without authorization in case there is some security issue, but they are less likely to be able to do more than that.

Comment: @MarkKaplun No, not like that Mark... After a discussion with client, I (again I repeat "I") will add client to my system . To save time, I am going to automatically install the WordPress when I add a client to system. It save lot of time....

Answer (score 0):

Please check if PHP is running in safe mode.
excel_shell is disabled when PHP is running in safe mode.

You can check this running the phpinfo() function.

Tip: You could make a install script in bash and execute that from PHP.
This way it's easier to test on the command line first, and then wrap it in PHP.

Comment: Normal shell commands are working fine. The problem happenwith WP